Local Storage being updated on page load in Dash/Flask
I am trying to make a Dash/Flask app with localization, the localization slug is being stored in local stoage however when I change the language to for example Russian and the language is changed in local storage, then when visiting/loading a page the slug is changed back to english. In addition sometimes the when changing languages from the dropdown sometimes the page refereshes and changes the slug back to english, and some of the html is not being translated.
The expected results are on first load (when the localstorage is none or doesn't exist) the default should be english (en). However when you change the language it should be persistent and all pages should be in the chosen language on load without having to change again. You should only change to another language when you choose so in the dropdown.
I appreciate any feedback, advice, or assistance you have to offer.
Github Repo: https://github.com/devium335/dash-project
app.py:
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, State, no_update
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json
import os
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import flask

# Initialize the Flask server and Dash app
server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# Define global variables
type_of_token = ["bpe", "wordpiece", "unigram"]
sizes = ["5k", "15k", "30k"]
languages = ["en", "ru"]

# Function to load data from JSON files
def load_data(size):
    if size is None:
        size = "5k"
    json_directory = f"data/output/{size}/"

    bpe_set, wordpiece_set, unigram_set = set(), set(), set()
    
    for token_type in type_of_token:
        with open(f"{json_directory}{token_type}.json", "r") as file:
            data_dict = json.loads(file.read())
            vocab = set(data_dict["model"]["vocab"])
            if token_type == "bpe":
                bpe_set = vocab
            elif token_type == "wordpiece":
                wordpiece_set = vocab
            elif token_type == "unigram":
                unigram_set = vocab

    bpe_lengths = [len(token) for token in bpe_set]
    wordpiece_lengths = [len(token) for token in wordpiece_set]
    unigram_lengths = [len(token) for token in unigram_set]

    return bpe_lengths, wordpiece_lengths, unigram_lengths

# Function to load translations from JSON files
def load_translations(language):
    file_path = f"assets/i18n/{language}.json"
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            return json.load(f)
    return {}

# Function to load HTML templates
def load_html_template(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        return file.read()

# Function to translate HTML content
def translate_html(content, translations):
    for key, value in translations.items():
        content = content.replace(f'id="{key}">', f'id="{key}">{value}')
    return content

# Define the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        dcc.Store(id="language-store", storage_type="local"),
        html.Div(id="navbar"),
        html.Div(id="page-content"),
    ]
)

# Callback to update the navbar based on selected language
@app.callback(Output("navbar", "children"), [Input("language-store", "data")])
def update_navbar(language):
    translations = load_translations(language or "en")
    return html.Div(
        className="navbar",
        children=[
            html.A(translations.get("home", "Home"), href="/", className="nav-link"),
            html.Div(
                className="dropdown",
                children=[
                    html.Button(
                        translations.get("graphs", "Graphs"), className="dropbtn"
                    ),
                    html.Div(
                        className="dropdown-content",
                        children=[
                            html.A(
                                translations.get(
                                    "graph_1", "Token Length Distributions"
                                ),
                                href="/graph/1",
                                className="dropdown-item"
                            )
                        ],
                    ),
                ],
            ),
            html.Div(
                className="dropdown",
                children=[
                    html.Button(
                        translations.get("language", "Language"), className="dropbtn"
                    ),
                    html.Div(
                        className="dropdown-content",
                        children=[
                            html.Div(
                                translations.get("en", "English"),
                                id="set-lang-en",
                                n_clicks=0,
                                className="dropdown-item"
                            ),
                            html.Div(
                                translations.get("ru", "Russian"),
                                id="set-lang-ru",
                                n_clicks=0,
                                className="dropdown-item"
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    )

# Callback to display the appropriate page content
@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    [Input("url", "pathname"), Input("language-store", "data")]
)
def display_page(pathname, language):
    if language is None:
        language = "en"
        # Set the language to local storage if it is not set
        return dcc.Store(id="language-store", data="en")
    translations = load_translations(language)
    if pathname == "/graph/1":
        return graph_layout(translations)
    else:
        home_html = load_html_template("assets/home.html")
        translated_html = translate_html(home_html, translations)
        return dcc.Markdown(translated_html, dangerously_allow_html=True)

# Function to generate graph layout
def graph_layout(translations):
    return html.Div(
        className="container",
        children=[
            html.H1(className="title", children=translations.get("graph_title", "")),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="size-dropdown",
                options=[{"label": size, "value": size} for size in sizes],
                value="5k",
                clearable=False,
            ),
            dcc.Graph(id="distribution-plot"),
        ],
    )

# Callback to update the graph based on selected size
@app.callback(
    Output("distribution-plot", "figure"),
    [Input("size-dropdown", "value"), Input("language-store", "data")]
)
def update_figure(selected_size, language):
    if not selected_size:
        raise PreventUpdate
    bpe_lengths, wordpiece_lengths, unigram_lengths = load_data(selected_size)
    translations = load_translations(language or "en")

    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Histogram(x=bpe_lengths, histnorm="percent", name="BPE", opacity=0.6)
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Histogram(
            x=wordpiece_lengths, histnorm="percent", name="WordPiece", opacity=0.6
        )
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Histogram(x=unigram_lengths, histnorm="percent", name="Unigram", opacity=0.6)
    )

    fig.update_layout(barmode="overlay")
    fig.update_traces(opacity=0.6)

    fig.update_layout(
        title=translations.get("graph_title", ""),
        xaxis=dict(title=translations.get("token_length", "")),
        yaxis=dict(title=translations.get("percentage", "")),
        bargap=0.2,
        bargroupgap=0.1,
    )

    return fig

# Callback to update the selected language
@app.callback(
    Output("language-store", "data"),
    [Input("set-lang-en", "n_clicks"), Input("set-lang-ru", "n_clicks")]
)
def update_language(en_clicks, ru_clicks):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        return no_update

    button_id = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    if button_id == "set-lang-en":
        return "en"
    elif button_id == "set-lang-ru":
        return "ru"
    return no_update

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)

assets/home.html
<div class="home-container">
    <h1 id="home_title" class="home-title">Welcome to the Token Length Distribution App</h1>
    <p id="home_description">Select a graph to view:</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="graph_link_1" href="/graph/1">Token Length Distributions</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

assets/styles.css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: visible; /* Ensure dropdowns are visible */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000; /* Ensure the navbar is on top */
}

.navbar a,
.nav-link,
.dropdown-item {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1001; /* Ensure dropdowns are on top */
}

.navbar .dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1002; /* Ensure dropdowns appear above everything */
}

.navbar .dropdown-content .dropdown-item {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer; /* Make language options clickable */
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.container,
.home-container {
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0; /* Ensure content is below navbar */
}

.title,
.home-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar a,
    .nav-link,
    .navbar .dropbtn,
    .navbar .language-picker {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

assets/i18n/en.json
{
    "home": "Home",
    "graphs": "Graphs",
    "graph_1": "Token Length Distributions",
    "language": "Language",
    "en": "English",
    "ru": "Russian",
    "graph_title": "Token Length Distribution",
    "token_length": "Token Length",
    "percentage": "Percentage",
    "home_title": "Welcome to the Token Length Distribution App",
    "home_description": "Select a graph to view:"
}

assets/i18n/ru.json
{
    "home": "Главная",
    "graphs": "Графики",
    "graph_1": "Распределение длины токенов",
    "language": "Язык",
    "en": "Английский",
    "ru": "Русский",
    "graph_title": "Распределение длины токенов",
    "token_length": "Длина токена",
    "percentage": "Процент",
    "home_title": "Добро пожаловать в приложение по распределению длин токенов",
    "home_description": "Выберите график для просмотра:"
}


in display page, you return a store with ID language-store (so duplicated id components) but this time no local memory. the default being "memory" and not "local" that erase it.

@Frayal Would this also explain the random loading bugs? And how would I implement that into the code?

set the default value in the inital app.layout: dcc.Store(id="language-store", storage_type="local",data="en"). it will never go to None, so no need to default it

I have updated the code (https://basedbin.fly.dev/p/gAcbBn.py), however now the navbar isn't showing and whenever I change languages it is automatically changed back within ms
